# Avoiding gaps in an identity column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in `MS SQL SERVER 2008` and I have set its `primary key` to increment automatically but if I delete any row from this table and insert some new rows in the table it starts from the next identity value which created gap in the identity value. My program requires all the identities or keys to be in sequence.

Like:
Assignment Table has total 16 rows with sequence identities(1-16) but if I delete a value at 16th position

```
Delete From Assignment Where assignment_id=16;
```

and after this operation when I insert a new row

```
Insert  into Assignment(assignment_title)Values('myassignment');
```

Rather than assigning 16 as a primary key to this new value it assigns 17.

How can I solve this Problem ?

Comment: IF the record was deleted from the middle then What do you need? Do you want to reinitialize the identity values after the deleted row?

Comment: You can restart the identity value using this :DBCC CHECKIDENT('your_table', RESEED, 0)

Comment: Why do the numbers have to stay in sequence?  Are you happy with the idea of having the 'sequencing' column separate from the primary key, as described below?

Comment: Identity values should be treated as opaque blobs that just happen to fit inside `int` (or other numeric) datatypes. If you're relying in *any* way on the actual *value* of an identity column, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I've also re-titled your question. We have the tags for telling us what technologies are involved. And just about every SQL question will involve a query. When asking questions in future, please try to come up with an effective summary that is *specific* to your question. (Please don't effectively put the entire question in the title either)

Comment: Meredith Poor, because of space optimizations. a int fields uses double the space of a smallint field. if you have multiple FK to it in realy big tables, space scales quickly, so it would be much more space eficient to fill the gaps in the identity column

Answer (score 3):

Renaming or re-numbering primary key values is not a good database management practice. I suggest you keep the primary key as is, and create a separate column index with the values you require to be re-numbered. Then simply create a trigger to run a routine that will re-number every row in the order you expect, obviously by seeking the "gaps" and entering them with values incremented from their previous value.

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL Servers standard behaviour. If you deleted a row with ID=8 in your example, you would still have a gap.

All you could do, is write a function getSmallestDreeID in SQL Server, that you called for every insert and that would get you the smallest not assigned ID. But you would have to take great care of transactions and ACID.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you desire isn't possible  without some post processing logic to renumber the rows.

Consider thus scenario:

Session 1 begins a transaction, inserts a row (id=16), but doesn't commit yet.

Session 2 begins a transaction, inserts a row (id=17) and commits.

Session1 rolls back.

Whether 16 will or will not exist in the table is decided after 17 is committed.

And you can't renumber these in a trigger, you'll get deadlocked.

What you probably need to do is to query the data adding a row number that is a sequential integer.

Gaps in identity values isn't a problem

Answer (score 0):

well, i have recently faced the same problem: i need the ID values in an external C# application in order to retrieve files named exactly as the ID.
==> here is what i did to avoid the identity property, i entered id values manually because it was a small table, but if it is not in your case, use a SEQUENCE SQL Server 2014.
Use the statement UPDATE instead of delete to keep the id values in order.